# How do I recover bookmarks on chrome for Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, bookmarks

Alright so today, my chrome decided to just simply not load anything. No matter what url you visited, it just wouldn't load. However, when I browsed as a guest, chrome worked perfectly fine. So from there I found out that the issue was with my account. I tried removing my account from chrome then adding it back on, and then I realized I lost all my new bookmarks. Google was able to sync my old bookmarks, but my more important and new bookmarks were unable to get synced.

That being said, where does chrome store bookmarks so I can recover them?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You will want to edit this to explain all the ways you back up your Mac. If you don't use Time Machine or Backblaze or another solution this will be a pretty quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Open up "Finder" and go to Macintosh HD ->Users ->Your user name ->Library ->Application Support ->Google ->Chrome ->Default; in the Default folder, you will see two files (Bookmarks & Bookmarks.bak).

Step 2. Now, you need to copy, rename and save Bookmarks file to another location. Then, go back and delete the original file.

Step 3. Next (very important step!), go down to Bookmarks.bak and rename it to simply "Bookmarks"(leave out the .bak extension, and this will make your backup copy of the bookmarks as the original bookmarks folder).

Step 4. At last, close Finder. Restart Chrome window, you shall see all bookmarks you've collected coming back.

Comment: I remove all content in that Application Support folder when I clean the space for my Mac. And I didn't enable time machine. I'm really doomed now!